# Any other data format except 'csv' can upload to gae (google-app-engine)

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, upload, format

I can use 'csv' file to upload to gae,
and I want to know, can any other data format do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new bulkloader supports delimited (CSV, TSV etc) and XML formats at a minimum, but much like the old bulkloader, it's possible to support any format you wish. Here's my post on [writing custom importers](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Advanced-Bulk-Loading-part-3-Alternate-datasources) for the old bulkloader for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XML files to upload data to your datastore as described [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html).